# Python allows creation of objects without specifying the essential argument

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, default-arguments

I am new to Python OOP.

Consider this code snippet below:

```
class LinearTopo(Topo):

    def __init__(self, k=2, **opts):
        Topo.__init__(self, **opts)
        ...
        ...


LinearTopo(k=4) # Not passing the **opts argument
```

I believe, **opts is an essential argument which is needed for creating an object of class `LinearTopo`. However, Python allows to create objects of class `LinearTopo` without this argument. Could someone explain, how it is possible ?

Comment: `**opts` captures **zero or more** keyword arguments. Zero keyword arguments is perfectly legal. Why do you think it is required?

Comment: Note that even if nothing is passed as argument, `opts` exists in the function (it's the dictionary `{}`).